# Maximum value in a specific column of a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, row, max

Say we have a matrix with dimensions `10x2`. How can I find that maximum value of the rows for column `1` only in `matlab`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
A = rand(10,2);    % 10x2 matrix
max(A(:,1));       % max for column 1 of A
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When we say `10x2`, this means `10` rows and `2` columns, right? in your `max`, where `1` is inserted, doesn't this mean the first row?

Answer (score 0):

```
A = rand(10,2);       %10x2 matrix
Amax = max(A,[],1);   %max across rows
Amax(1)               %max of the 1st col
```

This is a more generic approach in a sense that it computes max across all rows first that can be useful for accessing multiple max elements.

Comment: i think it's more generic in a sense that it computes max across all rows first that can be useful for accessing multiple max elements